# Require two sign-in options on Windows 11 before allowing user to log on

Tags: windows, windows-10, security, windows-11, user-accounts

Is it possible to require two sign-in options on Windows 11 before allowing a user to log in? For example, if an account has a password, a pin, and a fingerprint, is it possible to require the user to submit at least two of these options before allowing them to log in?

Comment: Windows does not support what you seek to do

Comment: Yes,  Completely a User Option

Comment: Two-Factor Authentication requires commercial software.